# How can I validate dynamically added dependent calendar fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've a form on my website where I'm getting multiple event details from my customers. They can share event details and event date.

I want to let them able to add multiple events with details but dynamically. Currently I wrote JavaScript for this and it's working fine.

Now, what I want is each time the value for next date should be grater than the previous one. So If they added 2 events suppose, the date for the second event should be based on date for first event and should be greater and same is true for upcoming dates.

How can I do that?

```js
var tableCount = 1;
var index = 1;

$(document).on('click', 'button.add_time', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  tableCount++;

  $('#timeTable').clone().attr('id', "timeTable" + tableCount).appendTo('#table');

  $('#timeTable' + tableCount).find("input").val("");

  index++;
  $('#timeTable' + tableCount + ' .aa').html(tableCount);
});

$(document).on('click', 'button.removeTime', function() {
  var closestTable = $(this).closest('table');
  if (closestTable.attr('id') != "timeTable") {
    closestTable.remove();
  }
  tableCount--;
  if (tableCount < 1) {
    tableCount = 1;
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table" class="form-group">
  <table id="timeTable" class="tg">
    <tr class="form-group">
      <td class="aa">1</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4">
        <button class="btn form-control btn-danger removeTime">Remove Events</button>
      </td>

      <td class="col-sm-4">
        <input placeholder="Event Date" name="events[]" class="input-lg" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="aa">1</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4">Event Description:</td>
      <td>
        ​<input name="event_descriptions[]" type="text" placeholder="Event description:" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="my-5">
  <button class="add_time btn btn-info">Add More Events</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever user `inputs` the date in input box you can check if the date which he/she has enter is less then previous date by looping through all previous dates inputs using `each` loop and  depending on this show some error message.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var tableCount = 1;
var index = 1;
//on input of date
$(document).on('input', 'input[name*=events]', function(e) {
  //get that date
  var edate = new Date($(this).val());
  var $this = $(this).siblings("span.error");
  $this.text("")//empty previous error if any
  //loop through dates inputs
  $("input[name*=events]").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != null) {
    //get input value
      var sdate = new Date($(this).val())
      //check user input is less then previous date
      if (edate < sdate) {
        console.log("date is less then previous date");
        $this.text("date is less then previous date")//show eror
      }
    }
  })

});
$(document).on('click', 'button.add_time', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  tableCount++;

  $('#timeTable').clone().attr('id', "timeTable" + tableCount).appendTo('#table');

  $('#timeTable' + tableCount).find("input").val("");

  index++;
  $('#timeTable' + tableCount + ' .aa').html(tableCount);
});

$(document).on('click', 'button.removeTime', function() {
  var closestTable = $(this).closest('table');
  if (closestTable.attr('id') != "timeTable") {
    closestTable.remove();
  }
  tableCount--;
  if (tableCount < 1) {
    tableCount = 1;
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table" class="form-group">
  <table id="timeTable" class="tg">
    <tr class="form-group">
      <td class="aa">1</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4">
        <button class="btn form-control btn-danger removeTime">Remove Events</button>
      </td>

      <td class="col-sm-4">
       <!--added this to show error -->
        <span class="error"></span>
        <input placeholder="Event Date" name="events[]" class="input-lg" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="aa">1</td>
      <td class="tg-yw4">Event Description:</td>
      <td>
        ​<input name="event_descriptions[]" type="text" placeholder="Event description:" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="my-5">
  <button class="add_time btn btn-info">Add More Events</button>
</div>
```

Comment: "Hats Off your efforts !
What a brilliant solution. I wish I could have upvote for you 10 times !. It's working like a charm. Thanks and May Eishwar bless you alot.

Comment: Your welcome .. :) .Please modify above code according to your requirement .

Comment: There is one problem in this code that is making trouble for me. 
If you would add the 1-5 events and delete let's say no 2, the rest of events shows like 1,3,4,5. 
How we can make them auto adjust like 1,2,3,4 after deletion ?

Comment: Hi ,that's different question ..please asked new question for this would help you there ..:)

Comment: Hi !. I just raised a new question for you. Please have a look. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64353510/dynamically-readjusting-fields-sequence-on-remove-method